# Rails 4 - Eager loading with multiple ON conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Article` and each `Article` has *exactly* one `User` and *either zero or one* `ArticleVote`.

My code is:

```
@articles = Article
    .eager_load(:user)
    .eager_load(:article_vote)
    .where(article_votes: { user_id: session[:user_id]})
    .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    `articles`.`article_id` AS t0_r0,
    `articles`.`user_id` AS t0_r1,
    `users`.`user_id` AS t1_r0,
    `article_votes`.`article_vote_id` AS t2_r0,
    `article_votes`.`article_id` AS t2_r1,
    `article_votes`.`user_id` AS t2_r2
FROM `articles`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `articles`.`user_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `article_votes` ON `article_votes`.`article_id` = `articles`.`article_id`
WHERE `article_votes`.`user_id` = 1
ORDER BY `articles`.`created_at` DESC
```

The problem with this query is if no vote exists (which sometimes it won't), then no records are returned. What I really need is this (note the where is gone and the condition is moved to the left join):

```
SELECT
    `articles`.`article_id` AS t0_r0,
    `articles`.`user_id` AS t0_r1,
    `users`.`user_id` AS t1_r0,
    `article_votes`.`article_vote_id` AS t2_r0,
    `article_votes`.`article_id` AS t2_r1,
    `article_votes`.`user_id` AS t2_r2
FROM `articles`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`user_id` = `articles`.`user_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `article_votes` ON `article_votes`.`article_id` = `articles`.`article_id` and `article_votes`.`user_id` = 1
ORDER BY `articles`.`created_at` DESC
```

I saw in the documentation I can do something like:

```
has_one :article_vote, -> { where(user_id: 1) }
```

Which will put it in the left join vs the where, but this doesn't let me specify the `user_id` at query time, which makes it not viable.

Can this be done?